# how to add thousand separator to header tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add thousand separator to my header tag value using jquery.

```
<h5 class="formatvalue" style="text-transform:uppercase;">'+ value +'</h5>
```

please check below code. but it did not work well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formatvalue").html().toLocaleString();
    console.log($(".formatvalue").html().toLocaleString());
});
```

Comment: If you do not pass a locale argument to `toLocaleString`, the string returned will depend on the user's locale settings. It may or may not have a thousands separator. Is this what you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toLocaleString()` needs to be applied to a number, not a string, use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` or `*1` (or other method to convert text to a number):

```
var formatted = parseInt($(".formatvalue").text()).toLocaleString()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#result").text(parseFloat($(".formatvalue").text()).toLocaleString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="formatvalue" style="text-transform:uppercase;">12345.67</h5>

<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```